# How to Group by hour in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

hi i'm trying to group the data by hour in big

[image]

so how can I group the data by the hour to count the orders per hour?

Answer (score 1):

Use below

```
select date, 
  extract(hour from parse_time('%I:%M:%S %p', time)) as hour,
  count(distinct order_id) as orders
from your_table
group by date, hour
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]